# IEEE754Compatible=true doesn't return int64s in string format in ASP.NET Core OData 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, odata

According to [the spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html), OData v4 services should return int64 and decimal types in string format when `IEEE754Compatible=true` is included <s>in the `Content-Type` request header</s> in the `Accept` request header or the $format query string parameter.

Here are the relevant sections:

> **3     Requesting the JSON Format**
> The OData JSON format can be
> requested *using the $format query option* in the request URL with the
> *media type application/json, optionally followed by format parameters*,
> or the case-insensitive abbreviation json which MUST NOT be followed
> by format parameters.
>
> Alternatively, this format can be requested using the Accept header
> with the media type application/json, optionally followed by format
> parameters.
>
> If specified, $format overrides any value specified in the Accept
> header.
>
> Possible format parameters are:
>
> - ExponentialDecimals
> - *IEEE754Compatible*
> - metadata (odata.metadata)
> - streaming (odata.streaming)
>
> **3.2 Controlling the Representation of Numbers**
> *The IEEE754Compatible=true format parameter indicates that the service*
> *MUST serialize Edm.Int64 and Edm.Decimal numbers (including the count,*
> *if requested) as strings.* This is in conformance with [RFC7493].
>
> If not specified, or specified as IEEE754Compatible=false, all numbers
> MUST be serialized as JSON numbers.
>
> This enables support for JavaScript numbers that are defined to be
> 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 values [ECMAScript] (see section
> 4.3.1.9) resulting in integers losing precision past 15 digits, and decimals losing precision due to the conversion from base 10 to base
> 2.

This doesn't happen for me when using ASP.Net Core OData 8 (even though there are discussions on Github c.2016 where it appears to have been implemented in OData.net: e.g., [here](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/522)).

As a minimal reproducible example:

- I created a new project exactly as described in Microsoft's [Getting Started with ASP.NET Core OData 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio) tutorial.
- I added a new property `TestLong` with type `long` to the `Customer` model
- I initialised the property in the test Customers with `long.MaxValue`

Yet, I receive number formatted values in the JSON, instead of string.

**Using the Accept header:**
[image: A Postman request to the OData v4 service, including the parameter IEEE754Compatible=true in the Accept request header. The response is shown to have returned int64 formatted instead of string formatted values.]

**Using the $format query:**
[image: A Postman request to the OData v4 service, including the parameter IEEE754Compatible=true in the $format query. The response is shown to have returned int64 formatted instead of string formatted values.]

**UPDATE**

Following the comment from @Jonathan Alfaro, I investigated to try and find where the IsIeee754Compatible parameter is actually set. (No luck so far).

I created a new jsonwriter factory as described [in this dev blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/using-the-new-json-writer-in-odata/):

```
using Microsoft.OData.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace TestIEEE754Compatibility.Models
{
    public class CustomStreamBasedJsonWriterFactory : IStreamBasedJsonWriterFactory
    {
        public IJsonWriterAsync CreateAsynchronousJsonWriter(Stream stream, bool isIeee754Compatible, Encoding encoding)
        {
            return DefaultStreamBasedJsonWriterFactory.Default.CreateAsynchronousJsonWriter(stream, isIeee754Compatible, encoding);
        }

        public IJsonWriter CreateJsonWriter(Stream stream, bool isIeee754Compatible, Encoding encoding)
        {
            return DefaultStreamBasedJsonWriterFactory.Default.CreateJsonWriter(stream, isIeee754Compatible, encoding);
        }
    }
}
```

Which I injected as below:

```
var edmModel = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
    options => {
        options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents(
            "odata",
            edmModel,
            services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IStreamBasedJsonWriterFactory>(o => new CustomStreamBasedJsonWriterFactory());
            });
    });
```

And the `isIeee754Compatible` parameter is being passed `false` even though the `IEEE754Compatible=true` parameter is present (see screenshot below). So, clearly it doesn't seem to be set automatically. But I can't for the life of me find out where it can be set manually.

[image: A screenshot of a debugger stepping through the CreateAsynchronousJsonWriter method of CustomAsynchronousJsonWriter, showing that the isIeee754Compatible parameter is passed false even when IEEE754Compatible=true is passed in the request]

Comment: For whatever is worth... the header is not enough I think you also need to set this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.edm.csdl.csdljsonwritersettings?view=odata-edm-7.0

Comment: Thanks @JonathanAlfaro, it does appear to need to be set somewhere, but I can't find out where. Please see the updates above.

Comment: try to implement logging around the point where the JSON writer is created to ensure that the `isIeee754Compatible` flag is set correctly when the writer is instantiated. Make sure that the OData configurations are not being overridden by subsequent middleware.as a workaround you could manually convert these types to strings in your service code

Comment: It looks like this was a missing feature in ASP.NET Core OData 8's implementation. The team says they've fixed it now. Good on them for the quick turnaround! https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/1123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't fully implemented in ASP.NET Core OData 8. I raised an issue on GitHub and it was quickly resolved.

[The GitHub issue](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/1123)
[Feature is merged into main](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/pull/1141)

I've confirmed using nightly build `8.2.3-Nightly202312181316` that it is resolved. You just need to add `IEEE754Compatible=true` to either the `Accept` request header, or the `$format` query. There are no other changes you need to make in your code, OData handles it internally.

**Accept header:**
[image: Postman request showing a request to the OData endpoint including IEEE754Compatible=true in the Accept request header returns int64 types in string format.]

**Format query:**
[image: Postman request showing a request to the OData endpoint including IEEE754Compatible=true in the $format query returns int64 types in string format.]